# 'Equiwidth' sets

Tags: geometry

Here is a question that I've been thinking of for about a week:

Suppose we're living in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since we are living 'in' $\mathbb{R}^2$, everything on a plane will seem 1-dimensional. (That is, what we view is the projections)

Let's call a compact convex subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ '*equiwidth*' (or shortly '*EW*') if its width looks all the same regardless of our viewpoint.

(In a mathematical term,) a compact convex subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is EW iff $l(\pi_\theta (A))$ does not depend on $\theta$ where $\pi_\theta$ is the (orthogonal) projection into the line $y\cos\theta = x\sin\theta$ and $l(B)$ is the length of $B$. (The length is well defined for $\pi_\theta(A)$, which is just a closed interval.)

**My original question is to specify EW subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.** But I found out that EW subsets are uncountably many, so it might not be a good idea to classify all of them. I just want to know some general characteristics of EW sets or interesting properties of them.

---

**Edited:** And here is how I approached the problem.

Let's just consider EW sets with width $1$. I defined an operator $r:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by $r(A)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 : d(x,a) \leq 1, \forall a\in A\}$. It can be shown that $A$ is EW (with width $1$) if and only if $A=r(A)$.

I also defined an operator $C:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by $C(A)=\cup\{r^2(l) : l \text{ is a line segment in }A\}$. Actually, I wonder whether $C=r^2$ or not.

The reason I'm thinking of these operator is to 'extend' a certain subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a subset that somehow shares some properties with EW sets. That is, given a set $A$, we can extend it by iterating $r^2$ because $A \subseteq r^2(A) \subseteq r^4(A) \subseteq \cdots$. Therefore the 'maximally extended' one is $C(A)$=$\cup_i^\infty r^{2i}(A)$, and this satisfies $C(A)=r^2(C(A))$.

EW sets cannot be extended ($A=r^2(A)$), but this is not sufficient, as $r(A)$ has to be the same as $A$. So the problem is: for what set $A$ does its maximal extension $C(A)$ becomes EW set?

Comment: Aren't there just two of them modulo size: the circle and the [Reuleaux triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle)? **Edit:** Apparently not. These objects are actually known as [curves of constant width.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width)

Comment: Nope, there are infinitely many of them, I found. @hjhjhj57. For instance, we can make some EW sets by rotating a line segment in a certain way. e.g. divide $2\pi$ into 18 equal angles $\theta$, and rotate a line segment via angle $2\theta, \theta, 3\theta, 2\theta, \theta, 3\theta, 2\theta, \cdots$ fixing each ends alternatingly.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that there is a name for it @hjhjhj57